# slow read on openzfs/Linux via NFSv3 on Debian 10

Tags: debian, nfs, zfs, readwrite

because of my unanswered question : [qemu snapshot exclude device](https://serverfault.com/questions/1015917/qemu-snapshot-exclude-device)
i decided to use NFSv3 for the VM to handle user data.
Because of slow performance of BTRFS after maintance-tasks i use now zfs Raid1 Version: buster-backports 0.8.3-1 on the Debian Host.

When I copy data on the host there is no performance problem.

**BUT:** the performance via NFS is exorbitant slow; in the beginning for both write and read with 10 and 40 MB/s. After some Tuning (i think it was NFS with async) i got the writes to ~80 MB/s. Thats enough for me.
The reads stayed at 20 MB/s per device, yet.

Any ideas what to test? I'm new to zfs and NFS.

**Host:** Debian 10
**VM:**   Debian 10

**NFS:**
Host:    /exports/ordner    192.168.4.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check)
client:  `.....nfs  local_lock=all,vers=3,rw,user,intr,retry=1,async,nodev,auto,nosuid,noexec,retrans=1,noatime,nodiratime`

**ZFS dataset:**

Volume with:
 ....create -o ashift=12 zfs-pool ....mirror
sync=default

```
zfs set compression=off zfs-pool
zfs set xattr=sa zfs-pool
zfs set dnodesize=auto zfs-pool/vol
zfs set recordsize=1M zfs-pool/vol
zfs set atime=off zfs-pool/vol
```

**zfs-mod-tune:**

```
options zfs zfs_prefetch_disable=1
options zfs_vdev_async_read_max_active=1
options zfs_vdev_sync_read_max_active=128 (also 1 tested)
options zfs_vdev_sync_read_min_active=1
```

Can u give an advice?

Comment: my NFS configuration is build with /etc/exports; now i use the build in sharenfs feature while hoping zfs do some kind of magic in the background and my problems disappear but my nfs client could not mount the nfs share - :( <br> - Generell question: Why do the openzfs developer programm the buildin nfs configuration modul when they use the kernel-nfs-server, too? i dont understand such logic. Waste of human resources!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get better performance if synchronous requests are disabled: `zfs set sync=disabled tank/nfs_share`.

- From `zfs` manpage: `disabled` disables synchronous requests.  File system transactions are only committed to stable storage periodically. This option will give the highest performance.  However, it is very dangerous as ZFS would be ignoring the synchronous transaction demands of applications such as databases or NFS. Administrators should only use this option when the risks are understood.

Bear in mind that disabling `sync` could lead to data corruption.

Another option would be:

- Use a SLOG [1] (Secondary Log) in really fast and separate devices, like SSD disks (NVMe is ideal, SATA is acceptable).

On your tests, I've observed that maximum number of active threads for asynchronous operations were set to 1. That is too low, hence could lead to bad read performance.

I need some details about your system (disk information for the ZFS pool, system memory and CPU).

Here is a suggestion that you could use and tune for your system. It works pretty well for my 12-core system (at `/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf`):

```
options zfs zfs_vdev_async_read_max_active=30
options zfs zfs_vdev_async_read_min_active=10
options zfs zfs_vdev_async_write_min_active=30
options zfs zfs_vdev_async_write_max_active=10
options zfs zfs_vdev_scrub_min_active=10
options zfs zfs_vdev_scrub_max_active=20
```

---

[1] https://jrs-s.net/2019/05/02/zfs-sync-async-zil-slog/

Comment: i think zfs sync is performance important for write transaction but i mentioned i deactivate nfs sync and so write speed was ok - but it still exists a read bottleneck. Also zfs sync is important for me and at the host there is no probleme at all. @Cache: my disks can write 120 MB/s each so why should i use cache?

Comment: I've updated my reply. Adding a code block inside a comment was pretty frustrating. Please take a look at the tuning part, you should consider raising the number of threads for asynchronous and synchronous read operations.

Write operations should also follow the same or a close number.

Please remember that the number of threads depends a lot on your system configuration. Setting this to higher numbers could cause more bottlenecks than better performance.

Comment: I would give you another tip. NFS is pretty ancient and has a lot of performance issues when running on top of ZFS.

Have you tried considering ZFS over iSCSI? On my setups I've dropped NFS completely in favor of ZFS over iSCSI. Sometimes there is a flat file (inside a ZFS dataset) exported via iSCSI and in other situations there is a ZVOL over iSCSI.

It works pretty well with outstanding performance.

Comment: thank u 4 your help, but your suggestions make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Some Updates:**

- i make some test with dataset as ext4 or xfs --> same results
- i use not a volume but the zpool direct as nfs share --> same results
- i test ganesha as nfs service --> the writes boost to 30 MB/s, but after retreat it stayed so i dont think this was the real cause for the boost
- i changed my configuration from network traffic through the router to a construct where the communication between host and vm to take place only in the RAM and test it with iperf

  --> to my surprise the bandwith dont grow over 60 MB/s for read and write although the CPU last was by 40%

  --> wtf - how awful -- only in the RAM no more - i do not  understand why - this is terrible slow

  - i do not believe that this is the typical performance of a actual debian kvm/qemu system

  **Maybe somebody has an answer.**
- interessting: i could not messure the udp-performance by comparisson because i get only 1 MBit/s - nfs with udp is functional but not error free with big data

Status: the speed with 30MB/s write and 50MB/s read is enough for me, but disappointing